# Combine if condition with hyperlink inside single display of strings

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code

```
<?php echo "<td class='name'><a href='humlaInfrastructure.php?title=".$humlainfrastructure["sn"][$i]."'>".$humlainfrastructure["title"][$i]."</a></td>"; ?>
```

I need to add another condition  inside this:

```
<a class="button red right" href="#" onClick="window.open('modules/addInfrastructureTitle.php','_new','fullscreen=no,location=no,width=600,height=200')"><strong>+</strong> New</a>
```

So the final code becomes

```
<?php echo "<td class='name'><a href='humlaInfrastructure.php?title=".$humlainfrastructure["sn"][$i]."'>".$humlainfrastructure["title"][$i]."</a><a class="button red right" href="#" onClick="window.open('modules/addInfrastructureTitle.php','_new','fullscreen=no,location=no,width=600,height=200')"><strong>+</strong> New</a></td>"; ?>
```

But it shows an error. How can I fix it?

Comment: you have quoting errors

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? When posting to SO, it is always helpful to include the errors you see on screen.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php echo "<td class='name'><a href='humlaInfrastructure.php?title=".$humlainfrastructure["sn"][$i]."'>".$humlainfrastructure["title"][$i]."</a><a class='button red right' href='#' onClick=\"window.open('modules/addInfrastructureTitle.php','_new','fullscreen=no,location=no,width=600,height=200')\"><strong>+</strong> New</a></td>"; ?>
```

use backslash `\` to escape quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php echo "<td class='name'><a href='humlaInfrastructure.php?title=".$humlainfrastructure["sn"][$i]."'>".$humlainfrastructure["title"][$i]."</a><a class='button red right' href='#' onClick='window.open('modules/addInfrastructureTitle.php','_new','fullscreen=no,location=no,width=600,height=200')'><strong>+</strong> New</a></td>"; ?>
```

For adding admin rights :

```
<?php  $str = "<td class='name'><a href='humlaInfrastructure.php?title='sdffd'>xfgdfgdfg</a>"; 

if($level=='Admin') { 

    $str .= "<a class='button red right' href='#' onClick='window.open('modules/addInfrastructureTitle.php','_new','fullscreen=no,??location=no,width=600,height=200')'><strong>+</strong> New</a>";
}
$str .= "</td>";

echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: how it would be if i have to add a role of Admin to access this task.
<?php echo "<td class='name'><a href='humlaInfrastructure.php?title=".$humlainfrastructure["sn"][$i]."'>".$humlainfrastructure["title"][$i]."</a> if($level=='Admin') { <a class='button red right' href='#' onClick='window.open('modules/addInfrastructureTitle.php','_new','fullscreen=no,location=no,width=600,height=200')'><strong>+</strong> New</a>}</td>";?>

Answer (score 0):

You try it...

```
<?php echo "<td class='name'><a href='humlaInfrastructure.php?title=".$humlainfrastructure["sn"][$i]."'>".$humlainfrastructure["title"][$i]."</a><a class='button red right' href='#' onClick='window.open("."'modules/addInfrastructureTitle.php','_new','fullscreen=no,location=no,width=600,height=200')"."><strong>+</strong> New</a></td>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your double quotes. Your PHP string is inside double quotes, so inside the string you need to replace double quotes with single quotes or prepend them with a `\`:

```
<?php echo "<td class='name'><a href='humlaInfrastructure.php?title=".$humlainfrastructure["sn"][$i]."'>".$humlainfrastructure["title"][$i]."</a><a class='button red right' href='#' onClick=\"window.open('modules/addInfrastructureTitle.php','_new','fullscreen=no,location=no,width=600,height=200')\"><strong>+</strong> New</a></td>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php echo "<td class='name'><a href='humlaInfrastructure.php?title=".$humlainfrastructure["sn"][$i]."'>".$humlainfrastructure["title"][$i]."</a><a class=\"button red right\" href=\"#\" onClick=\"window.open('modules/addInfrastructureTitle.php','_new','fullscreen=no,location=no,width=600,height=200')\"><strong>+</strong> New</a></td>"; ?>
```